# what does this output of ls mean?

Tags: linux, unix, ls

```
sysadmin@ubuntu /etc $ ls vsftpd*
vsftpd-users.db  vsftpd.conf  vsftpd.conf.backup

vsftpd:
vsftpd.pem
```

what is this `vsftpd: vsftpd.pem` part, and what does it mean? I never seen such before. does it mean that a file named `vsftpd.pem` exists in `/etc` ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I am curious because I would like to know which version reacts like this from the ls command.

Comment: @David 12.04 lts server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three files in /etc and one file in /etc/vsftpd/ that match the glob `vsftpd*`.

Comment: how can I make ls to output as `vsftpd/vsftpd.pem` ?

Comment: @thkang `find . -type f -name 'vsftpd*'`